# INNER JOIN 3 tabelas com tabela pivô

Tags: sql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Parte da minha base de dados consiste nestas três tabelas. E eu estou a tentar chegar a uma query de SQL que me diga os clients por sellers (vendedores), ou seja, por exemplo: O João (sellers) vende para 4 lojas (rua y, rua x, rua j, rua z) em que cada uma destas lojas pertence só a um cliente, neste exemplo a loja da rua x pertence ao cliente Nike, a da rua y ao cliente Adidas, a da rua j pertence também ao Nike e a loja z pertence ao cliente Billabong

Uma loja pode ter mais do um vendedor, ex: O João vende ténis e o Tomás vende casacosà  mesma loja.

Relações:

sellers->stores: muitos para muitos (tabela pivô: stores_sellers)

clients->stores: um para muitos

Com base no exemplo acima queria uma query que me dissesse os clientes do João através das lojas que ele possui. Resultado seria: (Nike, Adidas, Billabong)

Comment: Poste o que você já tentou fazer

Comment: Tentei com eloquent (laravel) mas tenho de ir com 'raw sql', visto que não existe esta relação predefinida em laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sellers
INNER JOIN store_sellers ON sellers.id = store_sellers.id_sellers
INNER JOIN store ON store.id = store_sellers.id_store
```